# Is there a way to open tmux while inside vim?

Tags: vim, tmux

Lets say I open vim to edit a file but I forgot to open tmux, I would usually quit vim then run the tmux command then run vim again, is there a way to streamline this to open tmux while in vim. I tried `:!tmux` in vim, but it seems to create a separate instance of tmux.

Comment: you could use `:mksession` to save the current vim environment then close it, open tmux, and load back the session.

Answer (score 0):

You might use [vimux](https://github.com/benmills/vimux)
to easily interact with tmux from vim.

A writeup of vimux can be found in the article
[Vimux: Simple Vim and Tmux Integration](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/vimux-simple-vim-and-tmux-integration/), which also days:

> Once you have the vimux installed as a vim plugin you should be able to start vim and run `:PromptVimTmuxCommand`. If vimux was installed correctly you should see `Command?`. You can then type any command to be executed and watch vimux create a pane for you.

[image]